# What's the Issue with Modeling Admissions as Multinomial?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, modeling, multinomial-distribution

I am reading Chapter 4 (Testing and Confidence Regions: Basic Theory) of [*Mathematical Statistics* by Bickel and Doksum](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/mono/10.1201/b18312/mathematical-statistics-peter-bickel-kjell-doksum). In Example 4.1.1, the authors use the study of sex bias in graduate admissions at Berkeley as an example to illustrate the difficulty of specifying a stochastic model and formulating a task as a statistical hypothesis. Specifically, the authors state:

> [The Graduate Division of Berkeley] initially tabulated $N_{m1},N_{f1}$, the numbers of admitted male and female applicants, and the corresponding numbers $N_{m0},N_{f0}$ of denied applicants. If $n$ is the total number of applicants, it might be tempting to model $(N_{m1},N_{m0},N_{f1},N_{f0})$ by a multinomial, $\mathcal{M}(n,p_{m1},p_{m0},p_{f1},p_{f0})$, distribution. But this model is suspect because in fact we are looking at the population of all applicants here, not a sample.

**My question:** I am having trouble understanding why using a multinomial model is an issue. What do the authors mean by saying that we are looking at the population of all applicants instead of a sample?

Comment: It sound like their complaint is that you don’t need to do any modeling; you have everything. I see some merit to this but also find this, without running to my copy of the book to see the context, a bit extreme. It’s reasonable to run a test to see if a significantly higher proportion of male students were admitted than female as some evidence supporting a claim of discrimination against the women.